# The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server could not INSERT

Tags: sql

I have currently setup a linked server.
We have two SQL servers: server A, server B
On server A i have create a linked server to server B

Now on server A i must do a insert on server B DB.
My select works fine.
Also i have given full access to the user.
Am getting the following error below:

> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "serverB" returned message "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.".
>
> Msg 7344, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "serverb" could not INSERT INTO table "[serverb].[Data].[dbo].[test]" because of column "test_ID". The user did not have permission to write to the column

Comment: What's unclear about that error message? Whatever login you're using to connect to serverb doesn't have the access permissions necessary to do what you need to do, so you need to figure out what permissions it needs and get them added.

Comment: I have test all permission i also use login Sa i get the same error

Comment: Is test_id an identity column which doesn't allow inserts?

Answer (score 2):

I've just had the same problem, and as Ben suggested above, it does seem related to an identity column. It's not a permissions problem, it seems that if you're inserting into unspecified columns over a linked server, SQL won't increment the destination identity column but instead gives you the misleading error message.
So instead of doing what I initially did (and I guess what you did) and running:

```
INSERT dbo.tblA
SELECT * FROM RemoteServer.RemoteDB.dbo.tblA
```

try specifying the columns:

```
INSERT dbo.tblA (ColB, ColC)
SELECT ColB, ColC FROM RemoteServer.RemoteDB.dbo.tblA.
```

but omit the identity column.

It worked for me in SQL2014.